# When fetch entity with colllections Hibernate N+1 Problem with JOIN FETCH

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with N+1 problem, when I tried to fetch entities with collection of childs or without childs when the category has parent,

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Category extends AbstractJpaAudit {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_category_id")
    private Category category;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Category> childs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And I have repository like this

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Category> {
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Category c JOIN FETCH c.childs WHERE c.name = :name ")
    Optional<Category> findByName(final @Param("name") String name);
}
```

Service like this

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CategoryService {

    private final CategoryEntityService categoryEntityService;
    private final CategoryMapper categoryMapper;
    private final AbstractSpecificationResolver<Category> specificationResolver;

    /**
     * Used to search for a specific category by name or throw exception if the category is not found.
     *
     * @param name of category
     * @return fetched {@link CategoryApi}
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public CategoryApi findByName(final String name) {
        return categoryMapper.toApi(categoryEntityService.findByName(name)
                                                         .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Category with name " + name + " does not exist")));
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<CategoryApi> findAll(final Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        return categoryEntityService.findAll(specificationResolver.resolveAll(parameters))
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(categoryMapper::toApi)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And mapper like this

```
    @Override
    public CategoryApi toApi(final Category category) {
        if (category == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return CategoryApi.builder()
                          .id(category.getId())
                          .parent(getWithoutChilds(category.getCategory()))
                          .description(category.getDescription())
                          .name(category.getName())
                          .childs(category.getChilds()
                                          .stream()
                                          .map(this::toApi)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                          .build();
    }

    private CategoryApi getWithoutChilds(final Category category) {
        if (category == null) return null;

        return CategoryApi.builder()
                          .id(category.getId())
                          .parent(getWithoutChilds(category.getCategory()))
                          .description(category.getDescription())
                          .name(category.getName())
                          .build();
    }
```

The main problem, that when mapper map childs, thats give N+1 problem, but I have JOIN FETCH in CategoryRepository, so why this not work?
[image: On this picture you can see 3 queries, thats happens when I thy to fetch category with childs]

Comment: `JOIN FETCH` won't resolve it recursively.

Comment: what i should to do? or just fetch it via additional querty and populate them all together?

Comment: ideally not store a tree-like structure in a relational database if you need to traverse it regularly.

Comment: I just dont sure that is ok to use another db, for storing only categories :) But ty i will think about it

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. We are using a query to populate all intances with a fetch left-join. And then we collect all children recursively.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make the association unidirectional and remove the category property.

You can also use the fetchtype lazy along with `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)` annotation for the `category` property. (needs hibernate bytecode instrumentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html).

> lazy (optional - defaults to proxy): by default, single point
> associations are proxied. lazy="no-proxy" specifies that the property
> should be fetched lazily when the instance variable is first accessed.
> It requires build-time bytecode instrumentation. lazy="false"
> specifies that the association will always be eagerly fetched

Using the second option will not create a proxy for the category field (null instead) but will still initialize it when accessed for the first time.